# how to Calculate response time in asp:repeater textbox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer

I Have a multiple text-box bounded with asp:repeater , I want to calculate time taken to type a text in that textbox, after textbox appeares. I tried it through onblur and onfocus events , but not working properly, as its taking onfocus time of next textbox while calculating time for previous textbox. 
My repeater code is as follows

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" autocomplete="off" EnableViewState="true"     onfocus="f1(this);" onblur="f2(this);"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And javascript code like this

```
        function f1(e) {
            var onFocusTextTime = new Date().getTime();
            alert("onFocus:" + onFocusTextTime);
            return onFocusTextTime;
        }
        function f2(e) {
            var responceForAnswer = "";
            var diff_result = "";
            var onBlurTextTime = new Date().getTime();
            alert("onBlur:" + onBlurTextTime);
            var onFocusTextTime = f1();
            diff_result = onFocusTextTime - onBlurTextTime;
            alert("diff_result:" + diff_result);
            var hours = diff_result / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            var absoluteHours = Math.floor(hours);
            var h = absoluteHours > 9 ? absoluteHours : '0' + absoluteHours;
            var minutes = (hours - absoluteHours) * 60;
            var absoluteMinutes = Math.floor(minutes);
            var m = absoluteMinutes > 9 ? absoluteMinutes : '0' + absoluteMinutes;
            var seconds = (minutes - absoluteMinutes) * 60;
            var absoluteSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
            var s = absoluteSeconds > 9 ? absoluteSeconds : '0' + absoluteSeconds;
            responceForAnswer = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
            alert("responceForAnswer:" + responceForAnswer);

        }
```

Comment: If any additional details are required then I will provide but please help !

Answer (score 0):

i just changed my code in following way and its worked

```
   var onFocusTextTime; 
    var onFocusTextTimeForPrevTextBox = new Date().getTime();

    function f1(e) {

        onFocusTextTime = onFocusTextTimeForPrevTextBox;
        onFocusTextTimeForPrevTextBox = new Date().getTime();
        return onFocusTextTime;
        }
        function f2() {
            var responceForAnswer = "";
            var diff_result = "";
            var onBlurTextTime = new Date().getTime();
            var onFocusTextTime = f1();
            diff_result = onBlurTextTime - onFocusTextTime;
            var hours = diff_result / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            var absoluteHours = Math.floor(hours);
            var h = absoluteHours > 9 ? absoluteHours : '0' + absoluteHours;
            var minutes = (hours - absoluteHours) * 60;
            var absoluteMinutes = Math.floor(minutes);
            var m = absoluteMinutes > 9 ? absoluteMinutes : '0' + absoluteMinutes;
            var seconds = (minutes - absoluteMinutes) * 60;
            var absoluteSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
            var s = absoluteSeconds > 9 ? absoluteSeconds : '0' + absoluteSeconds;
            responceForAnswer = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
            console.log(responceForAnswer);

        }
```